# JQuery ajax() returning 200 but not running success function

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm wanting to get back some data from a mysql table (just one field) for autofilling a form with that data.

I have a problem with the ajax() which returns ok (200) but it still runs the error function which I've added to it.

```
$('#group_id').on('click', function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "localhost/zamzamtravel/home/getPrevApplicantData",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        type: 'GET',
                        data: {group_id:1},
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        success: function(response,data) { alert(response); alert(data); },
                        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        console.log(xhr);
                        alert(xhr.status);
                        alert(thrownError);
                    }
                    });
```

I'm getting the json object back from my php script (im using codeigniter) as such from my controller:

```
public function getPrevApplicantData()
    {
        $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
        $data = $this->travel_model->getPrevApplicantData();
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

and this is the data which is retrieved in the model and returned to the above controller function:

```
public function getPrevApplicantData()
    {
        $group_id = $this->input->get('group_id');

        $this->db->select('general_info.address_telephone');
        $this->db->from('general_info');
        $this->db->join('groups', 'groups.group_id = general_info.group_id');
        $this->db->where('general_info.group_id', 1);
        $this->db->distinct();
        $this->db->limit(1);
        $this->db->order_by('general_info.customer_id','asc');
        $res = $this->db->get();


        return $res->result_array();
    }
```

the input type I've attached to the on click event is a radio button:

```
        <input type="radio" name="group_id" id="group_id">
```

(I'm thinking maybe I don't need a form, just make a normal button and when that button is clicked it can run the ajax function?)

I get an error in devtools in jQuery as well: `xhr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null );`

The array which I get back from the model function after the query has been stored is structured like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [address_telephone] => 1 somehouse avenue-highpoint-nc-27262-3365550493
        )

)
null
```

I'd really like to know whats wrong, all I was trying to do was a simple get and display :P

Comment: In you code you are requesting to localhost, are you requesting a different domain in production environament?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet no, it is within my application

Comment: Try: `success: function(response,data) {
 alert(response);
                            alert(data);    
                        }`

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet I just tried it, however get the same error, well not error per-se, but returning 200 but not running the success function

Comment: You're probably getting a type error when you do `alert('ok' + data);` since `data` in that case is an object and not a string.

Comment: Did you remove the `'ok' +`?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet yes i removed that

Comment: @Deryck alerting an object doesn't throw an error

Comment: should i look into json.stringify?

Comment: Is this failing in all browsers?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet Yes, in FF it gives me a 200 + "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character", same in IE11 and also Chrome

Comment: @Deryck is it? #groupid is a radio button

Comment: I don't suppose `$groupid = $this->input->get('groupid');` not matching `data: {group_id:1}` has anything to do with it?

Comment: @Deryck nice catch :P but it hasn't fixed the issue

Comment: I think that your json string retrieved from server is malformed or contains an invalid character.

Comment: @KhanhTO is it allowed to have '-' dashes in a json string?

Comment: remove the `<form>` tag unless you want to have the user submit something as well.  Or at least remove the `action="..." method="post"` from it.  I'm not expecting this to fix it, just more things to clean up

Comment: Go to the page manually with the url as: `/getPrevApplicantData?group_id=1` and make sure you get PHP full output like you expect

Comment: @Deryck yes, this is returned [{"address_telephone":"1 somehouse avenue-highpoint-nc-27262-3365550493"}]

Comment: it has to be the ajax not picking up the success function, why its not running it i mean

Comment: @a7omiton: I think the success function should be run but jQuery encounters errors trying to parse the string from server to an object to pass to `success` function (the string is not valid)

Comment: @KhanhTO but i get a json string back like such [{"address_telephone":"1 somehouse avenue-highpoint-nc-27262-3365550493"}]. thats running it without the ajax function

Comment: @a7omiton: I guess the problem is the underscore in `"address_telephone"`, try removing it to see if it works.

Comment: The JSON is correct as far as http://www.jsonlint.com is concerned

Comment: I've tried changing the fieldname to addresstelephone but to no avail

Comment: Can you update your post with all the changes you've made to this point so we can visualize it better

Comment: @Deryck yes i've done that

Comment: In my mysql query, I've hardcoded a value of 1 where it should be the $groupid passed by the ajax function for testing purposes because when I actually put in $groupid I don't have a way of actually seeing what was returned

Comment: I don't seem to understand why I'm getting a cross domain type error in jQuery xhr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null );

Comment: set your `url: ` to `getPrevApplicantData` assuming these files are in the same folder (unless they are the same file in which case, same url applies).

Comment: Use complete instead of success. Your Jason payload isn't properly set up for the Ajax call to recognize it as success

Comment: @Deryck I've tried that but same error :/

Comment: @KellyJAndrews I just tried but same result

Comment: @a7omiton I just put some code for you to try to replace your current AJAX with.  It shouldn't honestly change but try it out

Comment: Are you sure your input is getting to your model call? Not seeing how it gets there. Sorry, been a bit since I've done CI

Comment: @KellyJAndrews i dont know how to test for that (i tried but am boggled as to how to check if the result has reached the model or not because it only shows the xhr error in devtools so i dont know how to check if its actually taking the value or not)

Comment: You would need to log it,  or possibly do a print_r.  It may be a combination  of a couple things happening here. You may be hitting your page successfully,   but the Ajax call doesn't see it that way.  You should also get a tool for Chrome to test your routes.  Dev httpclient works

Comment: @KellyJAndrews Thanks, I'll do that. Going to take a break from this and work on something else. Ajax is grea...not really

Comment: Here is a good tutorial about CI and creating a rest service. REST is tricky, but worth the effort.  http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost/zamzamtravel/home/getPrevApplicantData", {group_id: 1})
    .done(function (data, response) {
    alert(response);
    alert(data);
})
    .fail(function( xhr, textStatus, error ) {
    var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
    console.log( "Request Failed: " + err );
});
```

Comment: I tried this but got this error in devtools: Request Failed: parsererror, SyntaxError: Unexpected token A

Answer (score 0):

I think your Json output from php needs a status item set to 200, then use a response object for the data.

```
{
  status : 200,
  response:{
      //data here
   }
)
```